# Can I set-up sendmail on a LAN without a registered domain for testing mail?

Tags: smtp, centos-6, sendmail

I am running CentOS on a server at home which I use for development of Joomla websites. After they are developed, I move them to a hosting service. While developing the Joomla website on my home Linux server I'd like to be able to test out the forms users fill out properly simulating the e-mail too. Can I run sendmail on a CentOS LAN on my home network even though it isn't registered as a domain, so that it can send out mail once a user fills out a form? What is required to do this? Can I use a GMAIL account as the mail sender? Would SMTP Auth required? Thanks!

Comment: WHy don't you just use `localhost`

Comment: Why do tou want to "send OUT email"?  You may configure sendmail/MTA server to redirect all outgoing messages e.g. to single local mailbox.

Comment: @Ramhound Such as user@localhost? But how is this going to send e-mail to the test user which may have an account on gmail?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Are you saying, to have a mailbox called test_user and then pop it from a workstation on the LAN?

Comment: It is one of the options.  Many people prefer to test email sending in development environment **without** sending out any emails.

Comment: @Edward_178118 - You asked how to send email without having a domain using `localhost` is that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the mails to youruser@localhost

If you cannot give a look to mailutils  (http://mailutils.org/).

If I remember well under CENTOS you can install with YUM

`yum install mailx`